# Mensajes vía texto o whatsapp con php

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Buenos días compañeros,

Tengo un nuevo proyecto sobre envío de mensajes ya sea de texto o whatsapp enviando notificaciones sobre programaciones que se realizan a nivel técnico. La verdad no tengo idea de como comenzar a buscar. Alguien me puede decir como puedo buscar y/o averiguar para realizarlo. Estoy usando PHP, Jquery y Mysql.

Si me pueden dar una idea de como o donde puedo averiguar a detalle de como hacerlo.

Para una idea más clara: Se comunica el cliente solicitando un soporte técnico, se programa un técnico para visita, se debe enviar una notificación al cliente informando sobre dicha visita, mandar los datos del técnico asignado y en dicho mensaje dar la opción de confirmar o cancelar dicha visita. Lo mismo cuando llegué la visita, enviar notificación informando que el técnico que se aproxima.

De antemano, muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar

Comment: ¿que has intentado?, para que podamos responderte debes de proporcionar más información acerca de lo que has intentado dando un ejemplo de tu código. estamos para ayudar, no para resolver el problema. 
lo que tu mencionas suena a un sistema complejo, no una simple pregunta, trata de reformular la pregunta.

Comment: por cierto, para el envio de mensajes por whatsapp o de texto es necesario que hagas uso de una libreria de un tercero, el cual tiene un costo sobre uso. un ejemplo es twilio